# Layout is Not Coming at Bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I written following in .xml file, instead of specifying

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layoutContacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewContactEntered"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Contact Number" >

    <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layoutDownButtons"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button 
            android:text="Balance"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="showBalance"/>
        <Button 
            android:text="Settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:onClick="showSettings"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want android:id="@+id/layoutDownButtons"   at the bottom. bot it is not coming at Bottom  .  I written android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"  for that still it is not working.

Comment: Post your full xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that solution helps you?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutContacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewContactEntered"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Contact Number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutDownButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="showBalance"
        android:text="Balance" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:onClick="showSettings"
        android:text="Settings" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the first "Linear Layout" you could use a "Relative Layout" and then write android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  in your layoutDownButtons "LinearLayout".